# buttonname.setBounds(xlocation,ylocation, width, height); doesn't work for me?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, jbutton, setbounds

```
 package com.tests;

 import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
 import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class LevelUp {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     final int width = 1000;
     final int height = width / 16*9;

 //buttons      
 JButton button = new JButton("Yus");

 //location
 button.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 50);

   JFrame frame = new JFrame("Level");
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setResizable(false);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("Biblioteker\\Billeder\\giggle.jpeg").getImage());
   frame.setSize(width, height);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

   //add to jframe
   frame.add(button);
```

}
}

Why wont this work? Also I am new to java and eclipse in general, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setBounds works in `null` layout. Add this line..

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that it was so simple, looked it up several times, but couldn't see why that would work, I dont understand much of this yet, thanks a lot!

Comment: Instead of making a new question thread, I have another problem, that I hope you could answer. When I use the debug instead of play, I should be able to edit the script live, right? (ex: edit the x and y position of the button and it would change live) It worked once for me, but now it doesn't. I looked it up and they said something about skipping break points, but that option is not toggled. Do you have any idea how to fix this? Thanks in advance, again.

Comment: What is your question? Change the location of button dynamically? is this?

Comment: Yeah like having the game running in the side and then changing stuff while its running. Like Unity 3D, you could click play and change ex. a position of a button or add one and it will pop up while game is running

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog() What is your thinking about it?

Comment: Nono, it's not a code, it's build in in Eclipse. Right to the left of the Run 'scriptname' button, there is a Debug 'scriptname' button. When you click the Debug button, you should be able to change or add in your script live, right?